# Get user requested url in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

i am working with spring security now. i need to get the url that requested by  a user. is there any way to get this through spring security configuration class?
any suggestions will be appreciated,

thank you

Comment: Yes. There is a way.

Comment: how? to do so here

Comment: Where do want to use it? You can Inject a HttpServletRequest into your @RequestMapping method and ask for the requested uri (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI())

Answer (score 2):

Make use of **RequestContextHolder** : Doc:http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html

> Holder class to expose the web request in the form of a thread-bound RequestAttributes object. The request will be inherited by any child threads spawned by the current thread if the inheritable flag is set to true.

```
((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getRequestURI()
```

or

```
((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getRequestURL()
```